# Javascript Integer interpreted as a string?

Tags: javascript, string, integer

```
var air = ITC.ITC.hotel.options.option[itc].packages.package[i].airfare - 1;
var opt = ITC.ITC.hotel.options.option[itc].packages.package[i].option - 1;  

console.log((air+1)); // Display 1 in console
console.log((opt+1)); // Display 7 inconsole
detailHtml += '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg nav-book" type="button" onclick="book_package(\''+ITC.sid+'\' , '+ITC.ITC.hotel.orig_hot_num_xsl+' , \''+(itc+1)+'\' , '+(package_idx+1)+' , '+(air+1)+' , '+(opt+1)+');">'+lang['book']+'</button>';
```

When I do inspect element, the two last parameters of the function book_package are integer of 01 and 61 but when I do air+1 and opt+1 in the console I get 1 and 7 ...

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg nav-book" type="button" onclick="book_package('3dd57f6c9e133553378e11d7521ab1be1463751663', 1, '1,3', 7, 01, 61);">Book Now</button>
```

EDIT 2

I also tried

```
var air = parseInt(ITC.ITC.hotel.options.option[itc].packages.package[i].airfare) - 1;
var opt = parseInt(ITC.ITC.hotel.options.option[itc].packages.package[i].option) - 1; 

'+(parseInt(air+1))+' , '+(parseInt(opt+1))+'
```

I cleared my browser cache, just incase, I still get the same issue

EDIT 3

New try, still the same issue ...

```
'+(1 + parseInt(air , 10))+' , '+(1 + parseInt(opt , 10))+'
```

Comment: Of course it is. It's javascript

Comment: What is air and what is opt?

Comment: I added air & opt in the op

Comment: You should give simplified examples. This is quite horrible to read. Often I find when I make simplified examples I realise what I was doing wrong in the first place.

Comment: When you inspect an element and read that value is `01`, you can be 100% sure that's a string. You need to coerce this into an integer before doing mathematical operations.

Comment: `(+air+1)` or `(1+air)` will both fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

At `detailHtml += '<button...` you are starting with a string ... that makes JS interpret everything as a string concatenation, while at the other pieces of the code you don't have any strings to mess things up!

Solution:

```
  detailHtml +=     '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg nav-book" type="button" onclick="book_package(\''+ITC.sid+'\' , '+ITC.ITC.hotel.orig_hot_num_xsl+' , \''+parseInt(itc+1)+'\' , '+parseInt(package_idx+1)+' , '+parseInt(air+1)+' , '+parseInt(opt+1)+');">'+lang['book']+'</button>';
```

```js
var a = 1, b = 6;

var r = 'Result';

r += ': ' + parseInt(a+1) + ', ' + parseInt(b+1);

document.body.innerHTML = r;
```

Comment: Yea but the addition is done with braces. Doesn't it perform them first, no strings so normal maths, then concatenate the values? Or does the existence of the initial string overwrite that?

Comment: the existence of the initial string overwrite that

Comment: I didn't mean specific with JS but with simple equations i always thought braces are executed first. Just done a quick fiddle and your right. Surprised ive never had to do this in the past so only found out now!

Comment: it's really kinda weird ... read a little more about it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/90203/why-is-so-bad-for-concatenation

Comment: I tried this solution '+parseInt(air+1)+'  , '+parseInt(opt+1)+' but I still get 01 and 06. I even tried to clear browser cache, just incase...

Comment: Then my guess is that you gotta check your variables type. Try using `air = Number(air)`

Comment: I agree check your variable type.  Check this out and see how the first alert has air as a number and the second one has it as string:  https://plnkr.co/edit/4Ll6juBC3BEu1MgdUhjx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Make it safe by being sure they are [integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
air = parseInt(air);
opt = parseInt(opt);
```

Comment: [*Always specify this parameter (`radix`) to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 0):

Double check your data types for air and opt.

Check this out and see how the first alert has air as a number and the second one has it as string: plnkr.co/edit/4Ll6juBC3BEu1MgdUhjx?p=preview